# Many zabbix-proxy, many zabbix-agent. Stop notification

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have a lot of zabbix-proxy who take care of lot of server with zabbix agent.

Each zabbix-proxy have around 10 zabbix agent under him.

If server who run proxy crash, I got 11 notification (proxy + agent).

Have you a solution for simply receive 1 notification (proxy) ?

I have read theses thread but I have not succeeded in apply them:

- [Stop Zabbix notification for nodes under zabbix-proxy when proxy service is down](https://serverfault.com/questions/601231/stop-zabbix-notification-for-nodes-under-zabbix-proxy-when-proxy-service-is-down)
- https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=37821

I don't understand how to integrate theses information with my configuration already in place.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Under the configuration -> actions menu you can specify to not send an email for a particular trigger/host (for each action you can define conditions).
You can create a separate action for this case for exemple.

Comment: Are you sure I can do what I want ?
I have zabbix in 2.4 version but I don't see anything for not sending mail. Sorry I'm begin with zabbix.

Comment: Yes you can. Under configuration -> actions you should have all your  actions defined at this time. On the right side you can see the operation for this action (Send message to user groups: Zabbix administrators via Email for exemple). Select the good one and check the "conditions" tab on the top. Here you can see all conditions required for this action. Add one in order to exclude triggers from zabbix-agent for some host (for example).

Comment: Ok, I see what you want to say. But how can I link agents-proxy in my condition. How can I say, "ok host01 is connect to proxy02"? I don't know how to write this trigger.

Comment: On the main action you can exclude all trigger from all your zabbix-agent behind your proxy and create a new action who send an email when the proxy agent is reachable and a zabbix-agent is unreachable

Comment: There what I have on Configuration -> Actions [Actions](http://www.noelshack.com/2015-09-1424767550-action.png) - [Conditions](http://www.noelshack.com/2015-09-1424767550-conditions.png). How can I link host to proxy ? I don't know how to do this trigger. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For the main action, in the conditions menu, add one like this : trigger <> Server {HOSTNAME} is unreachable (adjust with your trigger name, this is mine) for all the agents behind the proxy (or choose the trigger populated by the template). Create a new action, then add this four conditions : trigger = Server {HOSTNAME} is unreachable (same as previously) AND Trigger value = PROBLEM AND Trigger value = OK AND trigger = proxy {HOSTNAME} is unreachable (put your trigger name). Finally set Type of calculation to Custom expression = (A and B) and (C and D).

Comment: Ok, but there isn't a way to automate this ? I have more or less 500 hosts.Thank you again.

Comment: Create a template for all your hosts with a trigger concerning "host unreachable" or "zabbix-agent unreachable" and define this trigger for your new action. By this way all your hosts (and the new one) will match this rule.